# Ruby 2.0.0 fails to install because of openssl

Tags: terminal, ruby, openssl

I can't install ruby from source, on configuration (*./configure*) it states

```
Ignore OpenSSL broken by Apple.
Please use another openssl. (e.g. using `configure --with-openssl-dir=/path/to/openssl')
Failed to configure openssl. It will not be installed.
```

Even if I use the told parameter. *--with-opt-dir=/usr/local* doesn't help either. Notice, I installed the latest openssl (1.0.1e) from source too (it's located at /usr/local/ssh).

So later I can't use *gem install*, it just states:

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- openssl
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

How can I tell the ruby installation to take my installed openssl?

Comment: This is what finally solved the issue for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63914720/535339

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a similar issue on Tiger (yes, I'm using Ruby 2.0 on a Power Mac G4) – Ruby builds there just fine, but `gem install rails` fails with "RuntimeError: Unsupported digest algorithm (SHA512).".

Assuming you meant `/usr/local/ssl` and not `/usr/local/ssh` for the directory containing OpenSSL 1.0.1e, you should run `./configure` as such:

`./configure --prefix=/opt/ruby20 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/ssl`

The configure script will say that --with-openssl-dir is an invalid option.  It's lying.  Add /opt/ruby20/bin (or whatever you set as your prefix) to your PATH and enjoy Ruby 2.0 :)

Comment: That worked, great! _configure_ saying it is an invalid option really confused me, i never tried to build with that configuration. And yes i meant ssl - sorry for that.

Comment: In addition to this, I had to configure openssl with the special darwin flag e.g.  ./Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc when installing openssl.  Otherwise it didn't provide libraries for ruby to install with (or possibly just put them in a weird location)

Answer (score 2):

Rather than doing all the building from sources (and having to hunt down any necessary patches) why not try using [rvm](https://rvm.io) to build (and manage) your rubies, and [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) to allow you to build and install the necessary dependencies.

I have used these to get a ruby 2.0.0 build completed earlier today, although I haven't had a chance to check if it's fully functional yet.

Comment: I dislike using rvm and homebrew, further I never had any problems building a previous ruby version from source.

Comment: Adam S.: Apple is [deprecating OpenSSL as of 10.7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406946/why-is-apple-deprecating-openssl-in-macos-10-7-lion) which is part of the reason that it is broken.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the code page of the current terminal window running this code:

```
chcp 1252
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions